# questions with matrix derivatives, dererminat and trace

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

Recently i have some derivatives with matrix to work with. For Example:

$$\det \pmb{XA}$$
And i need to find the derivative  with respect to $\mathbf{X}$.

From Matrix cookbook i have 
$$\frac{\partial\ \det (\mathbf{Y})} {\partial x}= \det (\mathbf{Y}) Tr \left[ \mathbf{Y}^{-1} \frac{\partial\ \mathbf{Y}} {\partial x}\right]$$

So if:  $$\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{XA}$$

$$\frac{\partial\ \mathbf{Y}} {\partial x}=\frac{\partial\ \mathbf{X}} {\partial x} \mathbf{A}$$

Then $$\frac{\partial\ \det (\mathbf{XA})} {\partial x}= \det (\mathbf{XA}) Tr \left[ (\mathbf{XA})^{-1} \frac{\partial\ \mathbf{X}} {\partial x} \mathbf{A} \right]$$

From cyclic property of trace: $$\frac{\partial\ \det (\mathbf{XA})} {\partial x}= \det (\mathbf{XA}) Tr \left[ \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{XA})^{-1} \frac{\partial\ \mathbf{X}} {\partial x} \right]$$

How can i proced with the $\frac{\partial\ \mathbf{X}} {\partial x} ?$
If i want relative to $\mathbf{X}$ can i do $\frac{\partial\ \mathbf{X}} {\partial \mathbf{X}}= \mathbf{I}$ ? So that :

$$\frac{\partial\ \det (\mathbf{XA})} {\partial \mathbf{X}}= \det (\mathbf{XA}) Tr \left[ \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{XA})^{-1}  \right] ?$$

I ask this because i see some other questions here and them just trow the Trace operator away like:

$$\frac{\partial\ \det (\mathbf{XA})} {\partial \mathbf{X}}= \det (\mathbf{XA}) \mathbf{A} (\mathbf{XA})^{-1}   $$

How is that possible?

Any help is apreciated also books recomendations of the subject!

Comment: What do you mean by $\frac\partial{\partial \mathbf{X}}$? Do you have a definition for this?

Comment: just to add that your final answer looks as expected to me, i think the difference is just the matter of notations, i.e., transpose. But then you know how one could derive it, how the trace operator is thrown away (i have been through that pain as well).

Comment: @AlejandroNasifSalum I need the derivative in relation to the Matrix $\mathbf{X}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M = XA$ and $f = \det(M)$ (assuming $M$ is invertible).

Utilizing [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula), the differential of $f$ is
\begin{align}
df = d \det(M) = {\rm tr} \left( {\rm adj} \left(M \right) dM\right) = \det \left( M \right) {\rm tr} \left( M^{-1} dM\right)  .
\end{align}

And, $dM = dX A$.

Moreover, we will utilize the following the identities as well

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB) := \langle A, B \rangle$$ or $$A^T:B={\rm tr}(AB)$$
- Cyclic property of Trace/Frobenius product $$\eqalign{
  A:BC
   &= AC^T:B \cr
   &= B^TA:C \cr
   &= {\text etc.} \cr
  }$$

We compute the differential of $f$ first and then the gradient.

So, 
\begin{align}
df &= d \det \left( M \right) \\  
   &= \det(M) {\rm tr} \left( M^{-1} dM \right)  \\
   &= \det(M) \left[ M^{-T} \ : \ dM \right]\hspace{8mm} \text{note: utilized trace and Frobenius relation} \\
   &= \det(M) \left[ M^{-T} \ : \ dX A \right] \\
  &= \det(M) \left[ M^{-T} A^T \ : \ dX \right]   \hspace{8mm} \text{note: utilized cyclic property of Frobenius product} \\
\end{align}

Hence, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial X} f = \frac{\partial}{\partial X} \det \left(  XA \right) 
&=  \det(M) M^{-T} A^T  = \det\left( X A\right) \left( X A \right)^{-T} A^T.\\
\end{align}

Also, following the above procedure, one could show that
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial X} f &= \frac{\partial}{\partial X} \det \left(  XA \right) \\
&= \det\left( X A\right) \left( X A \right)^{-T} A^T \\
&= {\rm adj}\left( XA \right)^T A^T .
\end{align}

Comment: The  differential you use here is in relation of what? I mean its denominator. Also in $\det(M) \left[ M^{-T} A^T \ : \ dX \right]$ how did you trow the Trace/Frobenius away in the next step?